# Choropleth map does not display

Tags: python, choropleth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghBB1.png)

My code below does not display the intended output as shown on attached image. What have i missed on my code?

```
gjson=r'https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson'
Sanfransisco=folium.Map(location=[37.77, -122.42], zoom_start=12, tiles='Mapbox Bright')
Sanfransisco.choropleth(
    geo_data=gjson,
    data=df,
    columns=['Neighbourhood','Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.District',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime rate in Sanfransisco'
```

File "", line 11
    legend_name='Crime rate in Sanfransisco'
                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing bracket on the function. Try this:

```
Sanfransisco.choropleth(
    geo_data=gjson,
    data=df,
    columns=['Neighbourhood','Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.District',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime rate in Sanfransisco')
```

We can't tell if your code has any other problems because we don't know the form of your DataFrame.